# set the output volume in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume-mixer

how to set the volume of output created I want to set the output226.mp3 volume=2 as double I am using this command

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp3 -i s2.mp3 -i s3.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.2[a0];[1]volume=0.5,adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[2]volume=4,adelay=10s:all=1[a2];[a0][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3[a];volume=3" -map "[a]" output226.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the volume immediately after the amix, separated by a comma.

`ffmpeg -i s1.mp3 -i s2.mp3 -i s3.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.2[a0];[1]volume=0.5,adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[2]volume=4,adelay=10s:all=1[a2];[a0][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3,volume=2[a]" -map "[a]" output226.mp3`

Comment: There is one thing that I am facing ,when I merge multiple sounds with transition in ffmpeg, it lower downs the volume than the original volume. Any solution for it?

Comment: Get ver 4.4 and `normalize=0` to amix options.